# Similarity Matrix from DocumentTermmatrix

Tags: r, matrix, similarity

I need to create a similarity matrix from a document term matrix in order to perform maximum capturing clusturing on documents. Have only found a solution for distance matrix so far. Tryed the dist method but it gives me the wrong output. Is there a way to create similarity matrixes using R? I used the tm package for the following code but i am not constricted to it, if there is any other good package, let me know. The code so far:

```
install.packages("tm")
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("Snowball")
install.packages("RWeka")
install.packages("RWekajars")
install.packages("XML")
install.packages("openNLP")
install.packages("openNLPmodels.en")

Sys.setenv(NOAWT=TRUE)

library(XML)
library(rJava)
library(Snowball)
library(RWeka)
library(tm)
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPmodels.en)

sample = c(
"cc ee aa", 
"dd bb ee",   
"bb cc ee dd",
"cc ee dd aa",
"bb ee",
"cc dd aa",
"bb cc aa",
"bb cc",
"cc ee dd"
)
print(sample)
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(sample))
inspect(corpus)

corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeNumbers)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removePunctuation)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tolower)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stemDocument,language="english")
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, stripWhitespace)
corpus <- tm_map(corpus, tmTagPOS)
inspect(corpus)

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
inspect(dtm)

# need to create similarity matrix here
dist(dtm, method = "manhattan", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
```

The output for the given sample should look like this

[image: Similarity matrix]

The similarity matrix is defined as:

```
if (i < j) 
    a[i][j] = sim[i][j] 
else 
    a[i][j] = 0
```

Comment: you use `upper = FALSE` and you want an upper matrix as result...andd when I use your code your dtm has 9 documents with zero length terms...so a distance matrix here will be NAN here. I am really curious how do you kno the desired output?

Comment: when i inspect my dtm i have 9 documents including 9 terms... the expected output for the given sample is described in the paper about maximum capturing: http://140.134.131.64/wiki/images/8/82/2010-08-04_%28J-2010%29-_Text_Clustering_using_Frequent_Itemsets.pdf

Comment: @DIMI I get NAN matrix maybe because I haven't `openNLPmodels.en`
`openNLP` packages?

Comment: @agstudy it is possible, i added all packages i have tried so far to the above source code